# Migrating from concrete5 to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, converters, concrete5

I need to convert a concrete5 site to a WordPress site.

I can't find any plugins on both sides. There might be a solution via a feed ex-/import but it does not support all the contents and images.

Is there any idea how to do this?

Comment: Hmm, this may turn out to be tough to do automatically. My gut instict would be to do it manually unless it's tens of thousands of pages, in which case maybe one would need to whip up a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any pre-packaged solution for this. If there aren't too many pages (under 50 or 100), your best bet is to do it manually -- hire a temp worker for a day if you're a developer with a non-trivial rate.
If there are hundreds or thousands of pages, though, then you'll want to come up with your own automated solution. You can get some kind of XML representation of site content I believe via the Dashboard "backup site" functionality (not the "backup database" one). Or look into the concept of "Starting Points" in Concrete5 -- there's a free addon in the marketplace that lets you export site content in another XML format.

Then look into wordpress importers, and figure out how to transform the C5 output XML into whatever format your wordpress importer requires.

Best of luck.

Comment: thank you, both.

I'll do a mix of them. exporting as a XML, parsing and rewriting XML for WordPress importer. direct DB injection will be ignored by WordPress, so every single page have to be set manually to its publishing status.

Comment: I've similar task to do and wonder if/how you managed to convert your C5 site to WP?

Answer (score 2):

There's a ***[plugin](https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/cms2cms-concrete5-to-wp-migration/)*** at the WordPress plugin directory for an automated migration. It supports to migrate posts, attachments (images and videos), content images and list of other things, so it might answer your request.

The quick guide to the process includes following steps -

1. You install the plugin on your WP website
2. Create the account at the service
3. Download the bridge folder and connect to your concrete5 website via FTP
4. Choose the entities you want to migrate
5. Try the demo migration (it migrates up to 10 posts)
6. If you like it you can try the full migration (it's not free)

You may refer ***[this](https://cms2cms.com/blog/migrating-concrete5-wordpress-full-length-guidance/)*** for more info & this service is also represented in ***[WordPress Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content)***

Hope it helps.